# CSS display: inline-block and width: 100% does not work on IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, css

CSS `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%` does not work on IE6 and IE7.
Does anyone have some solution? Thanks!

```
<style>
nav {text-align: justify;}
nav li {display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;}
nav span {display: inline-block; width: 100%;}
</style>
...
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home Page</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Clients</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <span></span>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Update:**
So it works fine also on IE6, but when the list has more words it looks not good-> *"Contact               Us"*:

```
nav { text-align: justify; }
nav * { display: inline; }
nav span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home Page</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Clients</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
  <span></span>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you need `inline-block` here for anyway?

Comment: It makes the list items scroll horizontally instead of vertically.

Answer (score 3):

For IE6 and IE7 you could try using (in a style sheet included with conditional comments)

```
display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

`zoom: 1` trigger `hasLayout` which is similar to the behaviour of `inline-block`.

I do agree with the above commenters that you should not have a `span` as a direct child of an `ul`, though.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- Correct your HTML - UL should only contain LI, not SPAN
- There is no such thing as a NAV element
- Try floating the LI's using float: left - you should also set a width on them
- If you want an element to fill the width of the page, use display: block; This will work in all browsers - providing your HTML is correct!

Take a look at the [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/), this should help you with your HTML errors - there's also a great validator plugin for firefox that does the job too.

Comment: `nav` is a valid HTML5 element.

Comment: IE 6 and 7 (and indeed 8) won’t apply your styles for the `<nav`> tag unless you first create a tag with that name in JavaScript. IE isn’t good with tags it doesn’t recognises (see e.g. `<abbr>`).

Comment: Not so hard to make HTML5 tags to work for older browsers:
  var e = ("abbr,article,aside,audio,canvas,datalist,details,figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output,progress,section,time,video").split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    document.createElement(e[i]);
  }

Comment: You could use modernizer.js or Html5 boilerplate to add HTML5 elements to legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I've not recreated the code but I can tell you that you aren't allowed a span element nested inside a ul like that. Try changing the span to an li with and id and seeing if you get any better results.

What are you trying to achieve with this?